# opencv_traincascade.exe error, where is the parameter folder?

Tags: opencv

when I call the opencv_traincascade, I get the error message:
Training parameters are loaded from the parameter file in data folder!
Please empty the data folder if you want to use your own set of parameters.

And my call command is：opencv_traincascade.exe -data datatrain -vec pos\pos.vec -bg neg\neg.dat -numPos 3424 -numNeg 3900 -numStages 16 -w 64 -h 64 -minHitRate 0.9999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -mode All
What does that mean? How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you stopped and retry to train the cascade? If so, I think you shall run just the `opencv_traincascade.exe -data datatrain`, if no, then make sure that the `datatrain` is empty

Comment: The datastrain foleder is empty. When there is the above error message, the opencv_traincascade.exe just crashed. Now I'm using the opencv_haartraining.exe, it runs normally.

Answer (score 0):

Problem disappeared for me when I recreated the folder in another computer with a slightly different image set. Then I copied the files back to my computer.